# The import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'am trying to import a class but the Eclipse doesn't recognize the downloaded libraries. I have tried to **Update** my Maven's project via **Maven-> Update Project** it did not help. I tried to remove all dependencies except selenium-java and it did not help as well as redownloading the project from repository after a maven project update. Please need a hand, have no ideas what else should i do?

P.S. I tried to download the project on another machine and for first it didn't work but after a second attempt it went well and compiled.

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inspecting `/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.8.1/selenium-firefox-driver-3.8.1.jar` in your local Maven repository. Perhaps it's corrupted.

You can also try building the project from command line. Simple `mvn clean install` in command line should print the same error as you get in Eclipse. This will confirm that you don't have problems with your Eclipse setup.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the selenium-firefox-driver jar file is corrupted or something indeed. After performing a maven build it shows the next warning http://prntscr.com/ims7g0
I've deleted my 3.8.1 selenium-firefox-driver and redownloaded it. Everything is fine, thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

1 . Check the Build path if it looks like image

[image: not proper import]

Or 2. if you can not see the highlighted class as

[image]

In this case re download the selenium jar or download another build